# Center images inside a div

Tags: html, css

I want to center(horizontaly) three icons(inline) inside a div by using css. My div is centered inside another div but I want to center the content(the three icons) inside that div.

```
<div id="browsers">
  <div id="browsers-wrapper">
  <img src="Images/firefox.png" class="browserIcons">
  <img src="Images/chrome.png"  class="browserIcons">
  <img src="Images/opera.png"   class="browserIcons">
  </div>
</div>
```

Also a useful article on centering content with css to understand more about the procedure?

Thank you!

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: Just posted the solution to my problem. Thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to do it myself! I still need to understand the basic around block and inline elements..

Thank you though.

```
#browsers-wrapper img{
   display:inline;
   margin:auto;
   width: 8%;
   height:auto;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this commands , it may works :

```
#beowser-wrapper img {
margin : auto 0;
display : block;
width : 100%;
}
```

I recommend to take a look in this tutorial which describing these elements 
[Learn CSS Layout](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html)

And in here You can also look into Inline and block elements that described by picture examples :
[What’s the Deal With Display: Inline-Block?](http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/)

I hope it'l help you enough.